# 'printf' with leading zeros in C

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I have a floating point number such as `4917.24`. I'd like to print it to always have five characters before the decimal point, with leading zeros, and then three digits after the decimal place.

I tried `printf("%05.3f", n)` on the embedded system I'm using, but it prints `*****`. Do I have the format specifier correct?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your format specifier is incorrect.  From the `printf()` man page on my machine:

> **`0`** A zero '**`0`**' character indicating that zero-padding should be used rather than blank-padding.  A '**`-`**' overrides a '**`0`**' if both are used;
>
> Field Width:
>   An optional digit string specifying a *field width*; if the output string has fewer characters than the field width it will be blank-padded on the left (or right, if the left-adjustment indicator has been given) to make up the field width (note that a leading zero is a flag, but an embedded zero is part of a field width);
>
> Precision: An optional period, '**`.`**', followed by an optional digit string giving a precision which specifies the number of digits to appear after the decimal point, for **e** and **f** formats, or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string; if the digit string is missing, the precision is treated as zero;

For your case, your format would be `%09.3f`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%09.3f\n", 4917.24);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ make testapp
cc     testapp.c   -o testapp
$ ./testapp 
04917.240
```

Note that this answer is conditional on your embedded system having a `printf()` implementation that is standard-compliant for these details - many embedded environments *do not* have such an implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I see the error I was making.  Got it working on the PC, my embedded system still not formatting correctly, will have to do a work around.

Comment: Note that Microsoft's printf() is apparently not [standards compliant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aky45ct(v=vs.100).aspx) when putting leading zeroes on a floating-point number.