# How can I implement a timer, using sdl2 libraries in C, making lunar lander game

Tags: c, printf, sdl-2, c-strings

I'm making a lander mole version (Atari 1979) in C.I need to implement a timer in my game and then print on the screen.

I'm using SDLDrawLine because i have a vector that represent's my charactes. I need my code to run a string of characters, that's good. I use the sprintf function to transform a number into a string of characters to print it on the screen.

```
char aux_str[MAX_VALUES];
sprintf(aux_str,"%d",*value); 
for(j=0;j<strlen(aux_str);j++){
    *tam_caracter_numero = letra_a_longitud(aux_str[j]);
    *ptr_valor = letra_a_vector(aux_str[j]);
    for(i=0;i<*tam_caracter_numero-1;i++){  
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(
            renderer,
            (*ptr_valor)[i][0] * escalado + pos_x,
            -(*ptr_valor)[i][1] * escalado + pos_y,
            (*ptr_valor)[i+1][0] * escalado + pos_x,
            -(*ptr_valor)[i+1][1] * escalado + pos_y
        );
    }
```

This works properly, but I need my timer to start in 0000, changing to 0001,0002,.... But when i transform my number in a string using sprintf, the results is only 1, and doesn't print de 0s. There is some function o some way to make this posible? That let begin in 0000?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf with leading zeros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007487/printf-with-leading-zeros-in-c)

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work.first,my problem don t consist of the printf function, but with sprintf. Then my problem is not to print on the screen, but I have to pass from 0001 (as a number), to a string of characters (with sprintf), then print it on the screen of my game with a sdl2 function. When hay use sprintf on 0001, i get a 1.

Comment: The format string specifiers for printf and sprintf are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To print leading zeros just use the format `"%04d"` instead of plain `"%d"` in your `sprintf`-statement.
- On account of timing the whole thing I'd recommend going through [Lazyfoos's SDL tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/22_timing/index.php) about timers.
  To get the time use `SDL_GetTicks()`. This will get the time in milliseconds since SDL was initialized. See the [man page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks) for more details on that.
  To use it as a timer you have to get the delta time since last call to `SDL_GetTicks` and update it as such.

```
    unsigned time = SDL_GetTicks();
    while(game_is_running) { // Your game loop or whatever thread
                             // keeps track of time
      unsigned now = SDL_GetTicks();
      unsigned delta_time = now - time;
      // Either delay next frame to get a stable FPS and/or use it as
      // calculation in physics/collision

      // Update the time
      time = now;
    }
```

`SDL_GetTime` is expensive so I would not recommend calling it more than once per loop.

Off-topic: I also wouldn't recommend allocating a string repeatedly in a loop. instead allocate once and overwrite every iteration.

edit: In my "off-topic"-comment I am referring to `aux_str[MAX_VALUES];`, even though it's 1 instruction it's still unnecessary if it's inside OP's gameloop.

Comment: You are wrong in offtopic message. It doesn't matter where to introduce an array of chars because in any case this array will be allocated once (on stack) at the begin of the function execution.

Comment: No I am not. It is a concern for performance. allocating + writing bytes to an array is heavier for the cpu than just overwriting an existing array. Hopefully the compiler already catches this minor flaw and allocates the array beforehand.
-- Which is also partly why we don't create a new variable at the beginning of each loop for the time keeping.

Comment: What string allocation are you referring to? I don't see anything in either the code you posted or in the OPs code. And I don't understand "create a new variable at the beginning of each loop" comment. Can you clarify what you are referring to? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "allocating"? `char aux_str[MAX_VALUES];` - is one CPU instruction and doesn't depend on a place in code, where you declared it. It is not a dynamic allocation (which is expensive), it is stack allocation (which is not).

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: You are right if it's allocated inside a function, however I am assuming that it's either inside or outside his game-loop. Allocating and throwing it away is just wasted CPU-cycles if he could instead allocate once. that's all.